# Coulombs Law step by step help

Tags: forces, coulombs-law

How do you calculate the the magnitude of the total force of three charges and also the angle it makes with the x-axis? Knowing the magnitude and also the 2d co ordinates of the charges.

I have deliberately not given any specific values because this is not homework its a question from old exam paper and I want to know how to do it because I have a gut feeling it will be on the mid term and I honestly don't know what to do so if somebody could give me a step by step that would be great!

The only thing I know for definite I use the below formula but that's the only a clue I got from my tutor but I don't know how to use it I don't even know where to start I have no examples or anything.

$$K_0\frac{Q_1Q_2}{d^2}\hat r$$

Comment: Do you understand what the symbols in Coulomb's law mean?

Answer (score 2):

Here's the crux of the problem: break it up.

As an example, let's find the forces on charge 1. First, we have to find the force on charge 1 ($q_1$) by charge 2 ($q_2$). We then use Coulomb's law,
$$F=k\frac{q_1q_2}{r^2}$$
We now have to find $r$. Using the Pythagorean theorem, $r^2=r_x^2+r_y^2$, so $r=\sqrt{r_x^2+r_y^2}$. If we know $x_1$, $x_2$, $y_1$, and $y_2$, we can write this as 
$$r=\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2}$$
Plugging this back into the formula for Coulomb's law,
$$F=k\frac{q_1q_2}{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2}$$
Plug in the charges, and you have the force between $q_1$ and $q_2$. All you have to do now is break this into its x- and y- components ($F_{1,2x}$ and $F_{1,2y}$), then find the force between $q_1$ and $q_3$, break that into its components ($F_{1,3x}$ and $F_{1,3y}$), and treat them like you would any other forces.

Add $F_{1,2x}$ and $F_{1,3x}$ to get $\Sigma F_{1,x}$, add $F_{1,2y}$ and $F_{1,3y}$ to get $\Sigma F_{1,y}$, the use the Pythagorean theorem
$$\Sigma F_1=\sqrt{\Sigma F_{1,x}^2+\Sigma F_{1,y}^2}$$
to find the total force on charge 1. You can do this for all of the charges.